# Power BI - Matrix Visual - Collapse to latest record based on timestamp

Tags: matrix, powerbi

Current Matrix:

[image]

Power BI only lets me select first or last color based on alphabetical order. Is it possible to collapse to latest record based on date?

For ID 987654, Most Recent Color should be Pink and Most Recent Value should be 8788.

For ID 123456, Most Recent Color should be Green and Most Recent Value should be 5900.

Comment: Go the data tab--> select the colour column and then go to ribbon and sort by that selected column i.e the colour column.

Comment: @Sam this sorts alphabetically. I want it to collapse down to the most recent record based on the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a measure for each value:

```
ColorMeasure = 
Var ID_ID = SELECTEDVALUE('Test'[ID])
VAR MAXTS = CALCULATE(MAX('Test'[DATE]),ALL('Test'[Event]),'Test'[ID] = ID_ID)
VAR VALUE_VALUE = LOOKUPVALUE('Test'[Color],'Test'[ID],ID_ID,'Test'[DATE],MAXTS)
VAR RESULT = IF(ISINSCOPE('Test'[Event]),SELECTEDVALUE('Test'[Color]),IF(ISINSCOPE('Test'[ID]),VALUE_VALUE,BLANK())) 
Return RESULT

ValueMeasure = 
Var ID_ID = SELECTEDVALUE('Test'[ID])
VAR MAXTS = CALCULATE(MAX('Test'[DATE]),ALL('Test'[Event]),'Test'[ID] = ID_ID)
VAR VALUE_VALUE = LOOKUPVALUE('Test'[Value],'Test'[ID],ID_ID,'Test'[DATE],MAXTS)
VAR RESULT = IF(ISINSCOPE('Test'[Event]),SELECTEDVALUE('Test'[Value]),IF(ISINSCOPE('Test'[ID]),VALUE_VALUE,BLANK())) 
Return RESULT
```

Output:

[image]